# Computer immediately shuts down when disconnecting charger

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, macbook-air

I am using a MacBook Air (2008-model) with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. When I disconnect the charger, the computer blacks out and shuts down instantly. There is no shutdown process, it just goes black and silent.

If I look at my Gnome panel (the status bar), there is no battery icon. What I want to know is what has happened to my battery, and whether or not I should buy a new battery.

Comment: It's a 9-year-old laptop, I'd imagine the battery doesn't work

Comment: We actually use 8 year old batteries for our UPS that still work well, so it could still be good, but could be some of the pins on the laptop (I had the power plug do "arc flash dying" once on mine), as those are the things that always seem to fail for me, but then I push my hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the age of the device, I believe @Ben is correct to determine your battery at the end of it's life.

**Just to be extra sure...**

You could try re-seating the battery and check to see if the Mac detects the battery afterwards.

**If not, you may need to invest**

You can find some batteries for old MacBook Airs [still for sale](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=16J-000D-0AKB6&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Notebook+Batteries+%2F+AC+Adapters-_-16J-000D-0AKB6&gclid=CN2T5-vr29ICFZdLDQodFBgBqw&gclsrc=aw.ds) for a fair price.  (Bear in mind, I am not sure if this is right for your exact model)

**Note**

Investing in an older machine is always risky considering the possibility of further deterioration.

Comment: Of course it's no surprise that the battery is bad because of the age, but the fact that the system shuts down immediately after disconnecting charger and the fact that my OS doesn't detect a battery made me think that it may be disconnected or something

Comment: Those are both symptoms of a dead battery.  If something is not functioning, it is very possible it is not being detected at all.  If it was failing even a little bit, your Macbook would detect a problem and tell you.  Although, feel free to try and re-seat the battery.  It is definitely worth a shot!

Comment: No problem, definitely let us know if reseating it fixes the problem too!  Any possibly answers are encouraged to be shared.